# How to close only one side of a FILE

Tags: c, macos, file, unix, pipe

I've got a `FILE *` that is opened for reading and writing.  Ultimately, this file is communicating with a sub-process, so I am writing data to the sub-process through this pointer, and reading data back.  The problem is, the sub-process is waiting for end-of-file before it will send any data back.  But I can't close the `FILE` without also being unable to read any data back.

How can I force the `write` side of the file to close or otherwise signal EOF so the process will stop reading data and send me its output?  I've already tried writing a byte with binary value of 4 (EOT), which some documentation has linked to "Ctrl+D" on the command line.

Comment: Does the `FILE*` refer to an ordinary file? Why not use a `pipe(2)` instead?

Comment: @Ulfalizer I'm trying to tie this in with existing code which expects a R/W `FILE *` everywhere.

Comment: Theoretically you can open the same file twice with different access mode. But I am not sure how good this idea.

Comment: @tivn the required sequence is: my process writes to sub-process. when sub-process sees EOF on its stdin, it writes data back to me, which I read.

Comment: Do you know how the `FILE*` is created? Is it just a regular file? For a stream socket, `shutdown(2)` can be used to close just one end (after you get the underlying file descriptor with `fileno(3)`, though that's a bit hackish).

Comment: Perhaps you can save current position, close the file, and then reopen, seek to the saved position?

Comment: You need to know exactly what's going on in the subprocess.  First - how does the subprocess identify "EOF"?  You have to figure that out first, because if the subprocess somehow thinks it's reached EOF before the parent process is done writing, you're going to get some strange results if whatever you're using to pass data is something like a regular file on disk.

Comment: How did you manage to connect `stdin` and `stdout` of the sub-process to a single `FILE *` in the parent process?

Comment: That's probably why pipes are unidirectional.

Comment: Is `freopen()` of any help? Failing that, maybe `fcntl()` and F_GETFL and F_SETFL (or maybe F_GETFD and F_SETFD) can help?  I'm not sure why the sub-process is not getting EOF when it reads to the end of the file.  Is the stream actually a pipe, or a FIFO?

Comment: @Ulfalizer I think it's created from a descriptor opened with `socketpair()`, but `shutdown` is returning -1 (invalid argument).

Comment: Can you tell what the arguments to `socketpair()` are? How are you calling `shutdown()`? You will need to pass it the underlying file descriptor (which you can get via `fileno()`) and use `SHUT_WR`. It's not guaranteed to work of course, and it's a bit messy to mix stdio with low-level system calls.

Comment: @Ulfalizer That worked, thanks! I was missing the `SHUT_WR` parameter.

Comment: No problem! Any other problems?

Comment: @Ulfalizer Always! It's just one thing after another... :-)

Comment: @Ulfalizer and to quote my high school drafting teacher.. "and then you die."